# RestTemplate - How to display HttpServerErrorException in right way - Exceptions (RestClientException, HttpStatusCodeException)

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

On the client side, I use `exchange` method of `RestTemplate` to make a `RestFul` web service call. The service call is placed in `try/catch block`. Everything is fine when the response code is 2xx.

I have a catch block that looks like this:

```
catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            String msg = String.format(
                    "Error getting book data for bookId: %s and author: %s",
                    bookId,
                    author.name,
                    e.getStatusCode(),
                    e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            LOGGER.error(msg);
        }
```

I would like to `throw new HttpServerErrorException()` and display all needed fields for frontend developer to display it.

I know that I should do something like `throw new HttpServerErrorException()`

I am not sure how to do it, any help apprecited!

Comment: Can you create a HttpException class with a few fields like message, statusCode,  etc.. and then serialize as JSON for the frontend?

Comment: Can you show me with code plese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution and that is to centralize error handling in one place, you can use for that a `@RestControllerAdvice` annotated class.

Here is what I added:

**CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse =
                new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                        request.getDescription(false));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse =
                new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
                        request.getDescription(false));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

**ExceptionResponse.java**

```
public class ExceptionResponse {

    private Date timestamp;
    private String message;
    private String details;

    public ExceptionResponse(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

**NotFoundException.java**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public NotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

In catch block, I implemented two working solutions.

**First solution:** to use HttpServerErrorException class

**Second solution:** to use custom class

```
 catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
                String msg = String.format(
                        "Error getting book data for bookId: %s and author: %s",
                        bookId,
                        author.name,
                        e.getStatusCode(),
                        e.getResponseBodyAsString());
                LOGGER.error(msg);
//Second solution: throw new NotFoundException("Book with id: " + bookId + " and author " + author.name + " doesn't exist.");
//First solution:  throw new HttpServerErrorException(e.getStatusCode(), msg);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could create an HttpException class where the format is known on the frontend. When you get a non 200 status code on the frontend you can serialize the response body as json and then pull out the relevant information from there.

```
public class HttpException {
    private int statusCode;
    public String message;

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, And how do I add it in my code above? Something like `throw new HttpException()` and what to put into brackets?

Comment: How are you returning a response from this method in a valid scenario? Not throwing the exception?

Comment: I want to throw exception but I don't know what is the best way, that's why I asked question :)

Comment: I found solution you can check my answer :)